# All about frontier (boundary) in topological space

Tags: general-topology

In Engelking (theorem 1.3.2 p.24) and Choquet (prop 6.6 p.17 and exercice 17 p.112), there are several facts about frontier (or boundary) in topological spaces, but I can't find counter-examples simple but not too trivial to some counter-intuitive results.
I guess it is because reasonning in the plane is too specific (metric space and separation...).

Let $X$ denoted a topological space. For instance, one surprising property is: $\bar{A}\backslash A \subset fr(A)$ **without equality in general**. A counter-example in $X=\mathbb{R}$ is $A=\mathbb{Q}$ ($\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\backslash \mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}\varsubsetneq fr(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$).

Other surprising fact is : $fr(\bar{A})\subset fr(A)$ **without equality in general**. (Same counter-example.)

In general, examples one can easily find involve dense subsets. For instance, a ball (open, closed, or neither the first nor the second) in the plane satisfies the equality of the inclusion above. I just can see it by calculating the sets, but what I want is to understand why it works in some case and not in others...

Can you help me, please ?
Is there explicit or exhaustive literature about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple counter-example in the real line. Hope it will help some people...

Let's take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\{0\}\cup ]1,2[\cup ]2,3[$. Then $\bar A = \{0\}\cup [1,3]$, $\stackrel{\circ}{A} = ]1,2[\cup ]2,3[$, and hence 
$$fr(\bar A) = \{0,1,3\} \varsubsetneq fr(A) = \{0,1,2,3\} \varsupsetneq  fr(\stackrel{\circ}{A}) = \{1,2,3\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

> In a topological space, $fr(A)=\bar{A}\backslash A$ if and only if $A$ is open.

Proof :

We define $fr(A)$ to be $\bar{A}\backslash int(A)$ where $int(A)$ is the interior of $A$ (the biggest open set contained in $A$). Hence we have $fr(A)=\bar{A}\backslash A$ if and only if $\bar{A}\backslash A=\bar{A}\backslash int(A)$.

By set-theoretic argument (using the fact that both $A$ and $int(A)$ are contained in $\bar{A}$) this happens if and only if $A=int(A)$. This happens if and only if $A$ is open (if $A$ is open then $A$ is the biggest open set contained in $A$, and if $A=int(A)$ then in particular $A$ is open).

Now $fr(\bar{A})=\bar{\bar{A}}\backslash int(\bar{A})=\bar{A}\backslash int(\bar{A})$ and $fr(A)=\bar{A}\backslash int(A)$. So both are equal if and only if $int(\bar{A})=int(A)$. I don't think there is a better caracterization of those last sets.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. In fact, my "surprising property" was not a real surprising one: it is easy to understand why there is only an inclusion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an open ball added of one point of its frontier...
Moreover, fr(A) is sometimes defined as $\bar{A}\backslash \mathring{A}$, so there is one implication which is very natural...

The second inclusion and its dual with the interior ($fr(\mathring{A})\subset fr(A)$) are more surprising, I guess... 
Any counter-examples with balls in the plane ? An explanation ?...